# Is there a relatively direct translation of the English slang term "dry"?

Tags: coloquialismos, transliteración

Is there a relatively direct translation of the English slang term "dry"? That is, specifically referring to unresponsiveness or lack of effort in conversation, especially over text.

Comment: I would not have said that was slang, nor restricted to conversation.

Comment: @mdewey When one sees how full of BS the internet can be, it's despairing. Take a look at this post: https://letslearnslang.com/what-does-dry-mean-in-texting/#:~:text=In%20texting%2C%20when%20someone%20describes,try%20harder%20with%20your%20messages. Is there any difference between that definition and the ones we use to qualify speech or text that is not text**ing**?? Geesus, drives me crazy.

Comment: I’m not sure ‘dry’ refers to unresponsiveness or lack of effort in conversation. To me (native English speaker) it has a sense of something subtle and (probably) at least slightly sarcastic https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/dry - so if ‘seco’ isn’t suitable, perhaps ‘sardonic’ (sardónico/a) or maybe ‘tongue in cheek’ or ‘droll’ https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/in-a-droll.527873/ work

Answer (score 1):

No se me ocurre una palabra en particular que destaque ni que esté en boga, mis sugerencias:

- Si es un calificativo para la persona: **monótono**, **superficial**, **gris**, **insulso**, **insípido**, alguien que **te hizo sentir vacío**, **aburrido**, **soso**, **la nada misma**, y prácticamente cualquier palabra que sea sinónimo.
- Si es un calificativo a la conversación o el discurso: se pueden usar los términos anteriores pero se admiten algunas palabras más, por ejemplo también se podría decir que la conversación fue **tediosa**.

Answer (score 1):

Si *dry* significa "seco" aplicado como slang a una persona o conversación apuntaría a su falta de vitalidad o sequedad en actuación.

### Marchito

> 1. adj. Ajado, falto de vigor y lozanía. [*RAE*](https://dle.rae.es/marchito)